# Makefile does not work properly for C program

Tags: gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, shared-libraries

I've done this Makefile with the following structure:

```
BIN_FILES = array cliente servidor

CC = gcc


CCGLAGS =   -Wall -g


all: CFLAGS=$(CCGLAGS)
 all: $(BIN_FILES)
.PHONY : all

array.o: array.c array.h
    $(CC) -c -Wall -fPIC array.c

cliente.o: cliente.c array.h
    $(CC) -Wall -c cliente.c

cliente: cliente.o array.h
    $(CC) -Wall -o cliente -ldl -lrt

servidor.o: servidor.c mensajes.h
    $(CC) -Wall -c servidor.c -lrt -lpthread

servidor: servidor.o
    $(CC) -o $@ servidor -lrt -lpthread

clean:
    rm -f $(BIN_FILES) *.o

.SUFFIXES:
.PHONY : clean
```

But when I try to execute it, it only works the first rule. Then the execution stops. My final objective is to make each rule work, because if I execute each rule separately it works:

```
gcc -c -Wall -fPIC array.c
gcc -fPIC -shared -o libarray.so array.o -lrt
gcc -Wall -o cliente cliente.c -ldl -lrt
gcc -Wall -o servidor servidor.c -lrt -lpthread
```

Thanks

Edit: 
Now I obtain the following error applying @Jens modifications:

```
make: *** No rule to make the objective 'array', necesary for 'all'. Stop.
```

Comment: Start fixing the syntax errors.

Comment: Edited the error, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The targets for cliente.o and servidor.o should use `-c` instead of `-o`, i.e. you want to compile to object files.

There's also no point in specifying header files as dependencies in targets cliente and servidor. The commands for these only link, but don't compile files.

```
servidor: servidor.o
    $(CC) -o $@ servidor.o -lrt -lpthread
```

There's also no point is specifying library options `-ldl` etc when compiling to object files with `-c`.

```
cliente.o: cliente.c array.h
    $(CC) -Wall -c cliente.c
```

Comment: I think I'm not understanding the last two corrections. Could you please add an example of what are you proposing?

Comment: @giorgioW Examples added. What you do, by the way, could almost be done with a much smaller Makefile, using make's built in rules. You are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is not the best way to do a Makefile, but I'm starting in this field, so first I'm creating elemental Makefiles

Comment: Now I obtain the following error applying your modifications: `make: *** No rule to make the objective 'array', necesary for 'all'. Stop.`

Comment: @giorgioW That's because there is no target `array: array.o` similar to those you have for servidor and cliente.

Comment: I don't need to make an executable 'array'. I only need 'cliente' and 'servidor' executables. 'cliente' needs to be linked with a dynamic library that we made.

Comment: Ok I've managed to do the Makefile that creates `cliente` and `servidor`  executables. The only thing that remains is to create the shared library `libarray.so` and I don't know how to do it inside the Makefile